# CodeIgniter, PHP, jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am wondering about how people go about using CodeIgniter and jQuery for AJAX.

In your AJAX request you have

```
{
  url : ???,
  data : {a:1,b:2},
  success: ....
}
```

So, how do you build the URL?

Do you

- have all your JavaScript in your view files, and just use `site_url()` to build the URL
- have all your JavaScript in external js files, have a header view you include that has something like `<script>var base_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';</script>`. Then in your external js files have `url: base_url+'rest/of/path/';`
- some other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have my all my js in an external file and load it in my template.

For specific ajax requests, just call the page as you normally would.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/login',
    data: blabla,
    success: function(data) {
    // do something
    },
    dataType: 'json');
});
```

In answer to your question, I've had no need to specify the base url, as putting '/' before the controller name sets the root of the site automatically. You could also use ../ etc

Comment: does just using `/` work when you are developing on localhost where the url is something like `http://localhost/myproject/`?

Comment: Ahh that's a good point. I normally change my hosts file when i develop locally and would set my base_url in config to something like `http://local.website.com.`. Or you could set up a virtual host within your apache config.

Comment: hmm, that is an excellent idea. how would you edit your hosts file?

just have `local.myproject.com localhost/myproject`? or am I completly wrong?

Comment: Have a read of this article: http://apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php I would suggest doing something a little simpler like `http://myproject` (just to save any mistakes). But basically you'll need to create a record in the httpd.conf of apache, then go into your hosts file and point 127.0.0.1 to myproject. That article should help out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

if you are writing your ajax in external file then you can define your base url in the view file like

```
<script>
     var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
</script>
```

Then on your external ajax file write

```
url : base_url+'controllerName/functionName',
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done by loading a view that contains your JavaScript.

I currently load JavaScript from a view at the end of the rendered page. Since it is a PHP file with html `<script>` in it, you can use the URL helper functions like `site_url()` to generate the URLs you need for each function.

An example view might contain:

```
<script>
$.ajax{
    url : "<?=site_url("controller/function")?>",
    data : {a:1,b:2},
}
</script>
```

That will get you CodeIgniter generated URLs for your JavaScript. You could even pass variables into the view for more control over your js.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I make a small javascript in my header, in which I create a base_url and site_url variable (usually being properties of an object I name CI, but that's a personal preeference). I fill these values by echoing the values with PHP. If you make that the first loaded script, you'll always have the site_url available in JS.

Since I'm on mobile I can't post the source now.